# Make a grid as big as the screen

Tags: html, css, grid

I need the grid ad big as the page (it should touch the top the bottom and both sides) and I'd like it to be non-scrollable.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="prova">One</div>
   <div class="prova"> </div>
   <div class="prova">Three</div>
   <div class="prova">Four</div>
   <div class="prova"> five </div>
   <div class="prova">Six</div>
   <div class="prova">Seven</div>
   <div class="prova">Eight</div>
   <div class="prova">Nine</div>
   <div class="prova">Ten</div>
   <div class="prova">Eleven</div>
   <div class="prova">Twelve</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 10%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
}

.prova{
      border: 1px solid; 
}

 .wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
   grid-column: 3;
   grid-row: 2 / 4;
 }
 .wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

I've read multiple questions but I couldn't find any solution that works fine for me.

As you can see in the picture above the grid doesn't touch neither the top or the bottom!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `gird-auto-rows` to use a percentage of the viewport height. Equal amounts per expected row. So in your case `25vh`. Then remove any padding or margin around the grid.

```css
html, body {
margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 25vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.prova{
      border: 1px solid; 
}

 .wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
   grid-column: 3;
   grid-row: 2 / 4;
 }
 .wrapper div:nth-child(5) {
   grid-column: 1 / 3;
   grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="prova">One</div>
   <div class="prova"> </div>
   <div class="prova">Three</div>
   <div class="prova">Four</div>
   <div class="prova"> five </div>
   <div class="prova">Six</div>
   <div class="prova">Seven</div>
   <div class="prova">Eight</div>
   <div class="prova">Nine</div>
   <div class="prova">Ten</div>
   <div class="prova">Eleven</div>
   <div class="prova">Twelve</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working!! The only problem that I have right now is that when 2 cells are overlayed the stroke of them it adds up and become bigger than when it doesn't happen! Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: Maybe look into `box-sizing: border-box` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I'm going to solve that in another way! With your solution (the solution above) grid is going below the menu and a part of it is cut. What could I to to anchor the start of the grid to the end of the menu? here's the link to see what I mean : https://civitonia.com/27051195

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to touches the top just remove the padding
And for other sides just set the width and height of the wrapper to 100vh and 100vw

Comment: I've already tried and it wans't working at all!

Comment: If you have a liitle space on top or any other sides try to set the padding and margin of body to 0 it would work